# Why don’t posts by unregistered users appear in the First Posts queue?

Tags: support, review, unregistered-users

Recently, I stumbled upon this post:

- https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/1141/149

It is by an unregistered user. It did not appear in the *First Posts* queue as shown by the [timeline](https://drones.stackexchange.com/posts/1141/timeline) and the *First Post* review queue shows 0 items waiting and 0 items reviewed today:

[image]

Is this intentional? If so can posts from unregistered users be added into the this queue as they still need to be reviewed for quality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posts by unregistered users do appear in the queue.

What you've stumbled upon is a post by a *deleted* user. The user deleted their profile almost immediately after posting the answer. We don't pull posts from deleted users into the queue because, with it being a deleted user, we don't actually know anymore whether it was a first post. It could very well have been a post by a high-reputation user that had their profile deleted shortly after they made the post.

Comment: Are review tasks that were generated while the account still existed invalidated once the account is deleted?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Yes, because they would no longer get pulled by the query for eligible tasks for that queue. And the invalidation script for that particular queue is simply find all tasks that are not in the list of eligible and invalidate them.